# ArcGIS 10 Rest services regulary stop working

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I have a problem with a new installation of ArcGIS Server.
The installation is ArcGIS 10 on Windows Server 2008r2 with IIS 7.
I have followed this guide to configure the IIS ArcGISServicesAppPool: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36887
I did this because my cache wouldn't work without it.

The problem I have is that regularly the REST services stop working. The url to /arcgis/rest/services still lists all my services but when I want to open one, I get an error that the service is not available.
Also when I want to go to the ArcGIS/rest/admin/ I cannot log in.

I can solve this problem by recycling the ArcGISServicesAppPool in IIS. Then I can log in to the rest admin. But then I still need to clear the ArcGIS rest cache before my services work again.

One thing I've changed was to set the Idle time-out in IIS for the ArcGISServicesAppPool to 0, because I noticed that every time after that time out, my rest services didn't work anymore (same problem). So after this change, the services will run much longer, but still after a day or so, I need to recycle and clear the cache.

I've done some more checks and I notice that every time the ArcGISServiceAppPool automaticly recycles (via settings in IIS) the services stop being available.
The solution again is to manually recycle the application pool and then clear the rest cache again.

I've solved my problem by adding ArcGISWebservices user to the Administrators group. Don't find it a clean solution, but it's a solution. Can there be other problems with this? Security?

Comment: Have you looked at the log files?

Comment: I think you can also schedule the recycle and cache clear.

Comment: This exact same thing happened to me, and I ended up reinstalling the software.  It was strange, the services would be available and then, not.  I even did a support call with ESRI and they were unable to determine what exactly was causing the services to become unavailable.  I had also followed the steps from the link in your question.

Comment: @kirkk What log files do you mean? The IIS log files in inetpub\logs are empty.

Comment: @bradn I'm trying that now, I'll see what the results are. Although it is hard to check it, because the failure doesn't happen at stricked times.

Comment: What about the [AGS logs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//0093000000mv000000)?

Comment: I don't see any errors or strange things in the AGS logs.

Comment: Are your services connecting to an external database? I have seen a similar problem when the database recycles and the services temporarily lose connection to it. I think that particular issue was supposed to be solved in version 10 though.

Comment: @mrohlf There is no service that connects to an external database. I really wonder what the difference between recycling the IIS application pool manual and automatically is...

Comment: @tmske Maybe it has something to do with the timing of the automatic recycle schedule -- if the error that causes this occasionally occurs after the auto recycle, it would make sense that you would have to manually recycle (or wait until the next auto recycle).

Comment: @mrohlf I've solved it by adding the ArcGISWebservices user to the Administrators group.

Comment: Sometimes ags can be installed even though the server you're installing it on doesn't meet all the [IIS requirements](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#/Vista_Windows_7_IIS_requirements/00890000000m000000/).  Have you checked to see if you're missing an essential IIS component?

Comment: I am getting regular non-response from IIS and my rest services. It takes 2 or 3 stop/starts of IIS to get the server back working again. I've made sure ArcGISWebServices is in Admin group as well as all necessary server groups. Any ideas welcome

Comment: @JimLandwehr If you ask this as a new question you will probably get some responses.

Comment: Your license is ok ?